# Part Number Generation in MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm trying to make a Part Number (PN) generator for my company using MySQL.

Originally, I made this tool in Excel. It works great, but it's starting to slow down hard from the significant amount of data being processed.
I believe that a MySQL database will be a safer and more efficient way of generating and storing this information.

Now that that's out of the way, let me explain the components and intended result.

Table 1: Compounds

Table 1 defines the material that our product is made from. Example compound code: KP75

Table 2: Sizes

Table 2 defines the size code for the product. Example size code: -2x5

Table 3: Part Numbers

We technically have two PNs: Semi-numeric code ("computer PN") and a Customer Facing code ("actual PN")

Example Computer PN: AS1000034
Example Actual PN: KP75-2X5

Currently, Table 1 and Table 2 are finished, I'm just trying to figure out how to approach Table 3. I'm thinking about using a view or a trigger, but I'm not sure if that makes sense considering how necessary it is for both the Computer PN and Actual PN to remain constant.

Additional Notes:

- The Computer PN is incremental.
- There are currently around 130 compounds and 2500 different sizes. That would mean that, ideally, when I add a new material to Table 1, 2500 new PNs would automatically be created in Table 3.

Sorry if any of this is a bit unclear - I'm still very new to MySQL.

Here is a further example of how I want the data to be assembled.

Table 1 - Compounds

- A22
- B75
- C10

Table 2 - Sizes

- -2X5
- -2X10
- -2X30

Table 3 - Actual PN Result

- A22-2X5
- A22-2X10
- A22-2X30
- B75-2X5
- B75-2X10
- B75-2X30
- C10-2X5
- C10-2X10
- C10-2X30

As I mentioned, I'm very new to MySQL and honestly I don't really know how to start here. I have started trying to use triggers, but I don't want to continue down this path for hours only to find out I should have been using a different method entirely.

Comment: can you please show expected output

Comment: Not even sure SQL is relevant to issue. I don't know enough about triggers and stored procedures to advise on feasibility. Might need script in whatever you are programming GUI (VB.net, C#, C++, PHP, VBA, etc) to save selected parts as a single value into field. I program with VBA behind Access and that's where I would create code to save. Otherwise, save each discrete element to its own field and concatenate when needed which is really best practice in view of normalization principles.

Comment: Every compound will exist in every size?  This seems very strange

Comment: Does sound like you want a unique constraint of (compound,size) on table 3, plus an auto increment primary key to generate the numeric part of the computer pn and perhaps generated columns for both pn.  An insert trigger on table 1 and 2 could add any missing table 3 rows, but again, it seems strange to automatically have all combinations

Comment: @ysth   OP here - Yes, I do want every compound in every size. It's just a standard for my industry. How would that trigger be worded to include every size?